# Can't access Hapi server inside Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, hapi.js

I built a simple NodeJS server with Hapi and tried to run it inside a Docker container.

It runs nicely inside Docker, but I can't get access to it (even though I have done port mapping).

```
const hapi = require("@hapi/hapi");


const startServer = async () => {
   const server = hapi.Server({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5000,
  });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/sample',
        handler: (request, h) => {

            return 'Hello World!';
        }
    });
     await server.start();
     console.log(`Server running on port ${server.settings.port}`);
 };

 startServer();
```

Docker file is as follows:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

CMD [ "npm","run","dev" ]
```

To run docker, I first build with:

```
docker build .
```

I then run the image I get from above command to do port mapping:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 <image-name>
```

When I try to access it via postman on `http://localhost:5000/sample` or even `localhost:5000/sample`, it keeps saying `Couldn't connect to server` and when I open in chrome, it says the same `Can't display page`.

PS. When i run the code as usual without Docker container, with simply `npm run dev` from my terminal, the code runs just fine.

So, I am confident, the API code is fine.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Can you try `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`? And are you sure, that the server actually runs?

Comment: the server definitely runs because i can see logs from Docker - "server running on port 5000"

Comment: Inside the docker image localhost does NOT mean the same thing as localhost outside of the docker image.   Bind to all network interfaces.

Comment: @pzaengar - thats the answer, please copy and paste as an answer

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @pzaenger on your HAPI server configuration change localhost to 0.0.0.0.

```
host: 'localhost' to host: '0.0.0.0',
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply remove it altogether.

You see, hapi will bind the server to an ip but that can only be known at runtime (the ip of the container) or localhost.

You could find a way to conditionally assign that to either localhost or the container ip...but that's just too much mental gymnastics for me today after 4 hours debugging :)